# Как узнать, входят ли координаты в область координат?

Tags: yandex-maps-api, google-maps-api

У меня есть координаты точки. Я хочу с помощью стороннего сервиса узнать, принадлежит ли эта точка области координат.
Область координат я экспортирую с Яндекс Конструктора, там она является зоной доставки.

Есть ли сервисы или иные решения на проверку, входит ли моя координата в область координат?

P.S. Решения от Яндекса не подходит, их API доступен только при выводе карты на страницу.
P.S.S. Нужного мне решения в Google Maps не нашёл.

Comment: попробуйте это https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3.45/coordinates#LatLngBounds.contains

Comment: область координат прямоугольная, круглая или полигон?

Comment: Можно обойтись без сторонних сервисов - использовать локально PostGIS и конвертацию областей в геомы. Это будет и попроизводительней и понадежней и с архитекутрной точки зрения предпочтительней.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29915728/14255891

Comment: Область представляет из себя полигон. Точка, которую нужно проверить на момент вхождения в область представляет из себя массив, внутри которого находится ширина и долгота.

Answer (score 0):

Вариант на PHP

```php
public function inPolygon($point, $polygon): bool
    {
        $countPoints = count($polygon);
        $y = $point['lat'];
        $x = $point['lng'];
        $j = $countPoints - 1;
        $inside = false;
        for ($i = 0; $i < $countPoints; $j = $i++) {
            $jY = $polygon[$j]['lat'];
            $iY = $polygon[$i]['lat'];
            if ((($iY <= $y && $y < $jY) || ($jY <= $y && $y < $iY)) &&
                ($x < ($polygon[$j]['lng'] - $polygon[$i]['lng']) * ($y - $iY) / ($jY - $iY) + $polygon[$i]['lng'])) {
                return !$inside;
            }
        }
        return $inside;
    }
```